# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, search, substring

The code is to search for a substring...the code takes in 2 inputs...the 2nd string is used to search...i.e  2nd string is smaller in length.

```
a=input("Enter the 1st string")   //Giving error here
b=input("Enter the second string")

com=""

for x in range(0,len(a)):
       com=""
       for j in range(x,len(b)+x):
                com=com+a[j]
       if(com==b):
       print "Match Found at" + str(x)
       else:
       continue
```

The code doest compile....pls help

Comment: It helps to add the error message you get when compiling, as well.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python 2.x, you need to use `raw_input`, not `input`.  `input` tries to evaluate what you enter as though it is Python code.  This is no longer true in Python 3.

Another obvious thing is that this:

```
if(com==b):
print "Match Found at" + str(x)
else:
continue
```

... needs to be indented like this:

```
if(com==b):
    print "Match Found at" + str(x)
else:
    continue
```

Comment: `raw_input` is only for Python 2.x; it's `input` in Python 3. I'd like to say give the OP the benefit of the doubt; but with the indenting errors I'm not so sure =)

Comment: thnx for the indentation....i changed input to raw_input ...still giving same compilation error at line 1

Comment: @katrielalex: Yeah, I was editing to add the difference between Python 2 and 3 when you commented.  And I agree, we really need to see the compile error.

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token '('
' a=input("Enter the 1st string")'

Comment: @Vinod K: Is this the entire code file?  I wonder if you have an unmatched open paren before this first line.

Comment: i have this bfore the code file...

#!/usr/bin/python

Comment: I typed it agn fresh....now its compiling....

Comment: @Vinod K: Yes, it worked for me after I changed to raw_input and put in the indentation.  Then I run into a run-time error, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 4):

[`b.find( a )`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Comment: thnx...actually wanted to implement it in the  above way only...i am new to python...